# magento2 : warning fetchall() can be memory inefficient for large data sets

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, extensions, meqp2

I am getting warning fetchall can be memory inefficient for large data sets. its working fine but not for MEQP2 its giving WARNING so how use alternate of fetchall() in the code

```
namespace Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ResourceModel;

class TranslatableEntity implements \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Api\Data\TranslatableEntityInterface
{
    private $resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
    public function getConfig($configPath)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION
        );
        $select = $connection->select()->from(
            $connection->getTableName(
                'core_config_data'
            ),
            ['value']
        )
        ->where(
            'path = ?',
            $configPath
        );
        $result = $connection->fetchOne($select);
        return ($result) ? $result:null;
    }
    public function setConfig(
        $configPath,
        $value
    ) {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION
        );
        try {
            $connection->beginTransaction();
            $connection->insertOnDuplicate(
                $connection->getTableName('core_config_data'),
                ['path' => $configPath, 'value' => $value],
                ['path', 'value']
            );
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $connection->rollBack();
        }
    }

    public function getTranslationStatusByProductId($id)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                [
                    'mp' => $this->resource->getTableName(
                        \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                        MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                    )
                ],
                ['mp.source_product_id', 'mp.order_status', 'mp.project_id']
            );
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            if (in_array($id, explode(',', $item['source_product_id']))) {
                return $item['order_status'];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public function getMarsOrderIdByMagentoProductId($id)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                [
                    'mp' => $this->resource->getTableName(
                        \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                        MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                    )
                ],
                ['mp.source_product_id', 'mp.project_id']
            );
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            if (in_array($id, explode(',', $item['source_product_id']))) {
                return $item['project_id'];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public function getAllTaskIdsOfParticularMarsOrder($orderId)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                [
                    'mp' => $this->resource->getTableName(
                        \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                        MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                    )
                ],
                ['mp.task_id']
            )->where('mp.project_id = ?', $orderId);
        return $connection->fetchAll($select);
    }

    public function updateTaskStatus($connection, $data)
    {
        foreach ($data['task_status'] as $taskId => $taskStatus) {
            $connection->update(
                $this->resource->getTableName(
                    \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                    MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                ),
                ['status' => $taskStatus],
                ['task_id = ?' => $taskId]
            );
        }
    }

    public function updateOrderStatus($connection, $data)
    {
        foreach ($data['order_status'] as $taskId => $orderStatus) {
            $connection->update(
                $this->resource->getTableName(
                    \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                    MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                ),
                ['order_status' => $orderStatus],
                ['task_id = ?' => $taskId]
            );
        }
    }

    public function updateFilePath($connection, $fileType, $taskId, $filePath)
    {
        $connection->update(
            $this->resource->getTableName(
                \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
            ),
            [$fileType => $filePath],
            ['task_id = ?' => $taskId]
        );
    }

    public function updateMarsOrdersByTaskId($orderData)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        foreach ($orderData as $orderId => $data) {
            $this->updateOrderStatus($connection, $data);
            $this->updateTaskStatus($connection, $data);
            if (isset($data['files'])) {
                foreach ($data['files'] as $fileType => $file) {
                    if ($fileType == 'translation_file') {
                        foreach ($file as $taskId => $location) {
                            $this->updateFilePath(
                                $connection,
                                'translated_file_path',
                                $taskId,
                                $location
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    if ($fileType == 'proofreader_file') {
                        foreach ($file as $taskId => $location) {
                            $this->updateFilePath(
                                $connection,
                                'proofreader_file_path',
                                $taskId,
                                $location
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function updateOrderStatusWhenAllTasksAreCompleted($orderId)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                [
                    'mp' => $this->resource->getTableName(
                        \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                        MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                    )
                ],
                ['mp.status']
            )
            ->where('mp.project_id = ?', $orderId);
        $connection->fetchAll($select);
    }

    public function getMagentoSourceAndTargetStoreLocaleBySourceProductId($productId)
    {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                [
                    'mp' => $this->resource->getTableName(
                        \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Model\ConstantsInterface::
                        MARSTRANSLATION_MAGENTO_DB_TABLE_NAME
                    )
                ],
                [
                    'mp.source_product_id', 'mp.magento_store_id_origin',
                    'mp.magento_store_id_translation', 'mp.translated_file_path'
                ]
            );
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
        $data = [];
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            if (in_array($productId, explode(',', $item['source_product_id']))) {
                $data[] = $item['magento_store_id_origin'] . '~' .
                    $item['magento_store_id_translation'] . '~' . $item['translated_file_path'];
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento's implementation of a query generator function `Magento\Framework\DB\Query\Generator` by default it will limit the results to 100, but you can change it.

Here is more how less how you would do it:

```
$batchSelectIterator = $this->batchQueryGenerator->generate(
     'value_id',
     $connection->select()
          ->from(
               //
          )->join(
               //
          )->where(
               //
          ),
         [YOUR_CUSTOM_BATCH_LIMIT]
      );

// Yield is what does the trick here :)
foreach ($batchSelectIterator as $select) {
     yield $connection->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: i just change fetch all to fetchone and the warning solved. but thankx for your answer.